# Updating records, getting successful message but data isn't being updated in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert-update

I am building a "edit_post" page for my site so users can edit what they have previously posted(duh), I am getting the notification "Updated data successfully" but the data isn't being updated in mysql

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$topic_id = $_POST['topic_id'];
$topic_data = $_POST['topic_data'];
$invisipost = isset($_POST['invisipost']) ? $_POST['invisipost'] : 0 ;

$sql = "UPDATE `topics` SET topic_data='$topic_data', invisipost='$invisipost' WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'" ;

$retval = mysql_query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close();
}
else
{
}
?>
```

Here is my form code

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Here are the fields in the form I am trying to update

```
<textarea name="topic_data" cols="50" rows="3" id="topic_data"><? echo $rows['topic_data']; ?></textarea>

<input type="checkbox" name="invisipost" value="<? echo $rows['invisipost']; ?>">
```

And the form submission code

```
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
```

I hope I have provided enough informataion.

Answer (score 0):

You query is still failing, you are seeing "Updated data successfully" because it is outside of the if statement.
Try this:

```
if(!$retval){  //query has failed, produce error
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{ //query is successful
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got "Could not update data" but didn't get any error messages beyond that.

Comment: what does your connection string look like

Comment: I know the database information is correct as it's stored in an include file on every page of the site and it works everywhere else but here, I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: ok, just make sure you have it setup with a `die ('cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());` incase it fails for whatever reason

Comment: Like this: `mysql_connect("host","user","password") or die("Unable to connect");`

Comment: Yup, set up like that 

<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die($connect_error);
?>